Can't update columnFilters with new columnFilter with the same id but "empty" value using Tanstack Table
I have a problem with implementing manual column filters with react tanstack table. When clicking button to remove filter I call removeSelectedFilter, where I update ColumnFiltersState (I'll leave the selectedFilters state here, because it has 0 impact on that issue). Firstly I filter previous ColumnFiltersState to get rid of object with id: filter.id and then I set the state to ...prev + new object with the same id: filter.id but value: []. Unfortunately state is not set to [...prev, {id: filter.id, value: []}] but []. I can see that in useColumnFilter custom hook in filters log and I have no idea why it's the case...
Simple example:
I start with ColumnFiltersState as [{id: "status", value: ["pending"]}], and click button to fire removeSelectedFilter. The filtersToSet will be an empty array so the return value should be [{id: "status", value: []}] but in console.log I see filters:: []. If instead of returning {id: filter.id, value: []} I put different id e.g. {id: "Status", value: []} I will see in console.log filters:: [{id: "Status", value: []}]. Does Tanstack automatically remove this state if it sees new empty value for the same id?
function DataTableFilters<TData>({ table, columnFilters }: DataTableFiltersProps<TData>) {
  const [selectedFilters, setSelectedFilters] = useState<ColumnFiltersState>(table.getState().columnFilters);
  
  const removeSelectedFilter = (filter: ColumnFilter) => {
    table.setColumnFilters((prev) => {
      const filtersToSet = prev.filter((f) => f.id !== filter.id);
      return [...filtersToSet, { id: filter.id, value: [] }];
    });
    setSelectedFilters((prev) => prev.filter((f) => f.id !== filter.id));
  };

export const useColumnFilter = (state: ColumnFiltersState) => {
  const [filters, setFilters] = useState<ColumnFiltersState>(state);
  const { updateSearchParams } = useSearchParamsUpdate();

  console.log("filters:: ", filters) //Example log
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const filtersQuery = filterToQuery(filters);
    updateSearchParams(filtersQuery);
  }, [filters]);

  return {
    filters,
    setFilters,
  };
};

I want to make it that way because in that case I will remove filter from URL if value of any filters is empty array. Thanks for your help

I think you are trying to remove a filter from existing filters, in that case you do not need to set that filter's properties. You should instead return the filters excluding the one you want removed. In your table.setColumnFilters call, simply return prev.filter((f) => f.id !== filter.id); should do the trick.

@codejockie It's not a case. I need to make it that way, because if I filter this old columnFilter I will get empty array [] in useColumnFilter (it's visible via console.log) so I won't be able to updateSearchParams (URL update), cause filters is []. If I have filters = [{id: "status", value: []}] I'll be able to map this empty filter to filtersQuery and with updateSearchParams remove it from URL and redirect to new URL

I think you have might be overthinking this. If filter is [{ id: "status", value: [] }], you are simply saying there is no filter provided for status since its value is empty. Isn't that the same as having it as undefined such that if filter is [] (empty) then no filter has been applied? My question is why do you need status filter to have an empty array as its value? What is the significance of the empty array?

@codejockie Maybe you are right, I will try to explain my view - Whenever ColumnFiltersState is updated the useEffect in useColumnFilter will execute. In useEffect I firstly remap exisiting filters to object {id: string, param: string}[] which represents URL query parameters. Then I call updateSearchParams to update the URL and reload the page so the SSR table will reload its data. But if updated filter is as you said undefined/[], useEffect will not execute so page won't reload and will still be localhost:5000/?status=asd. I can't call updateSearchParams in this removeFilter fn thou

In that case, you might want to update the filterToQuery function so it handles undefined. My thought is if you have no filters set then filters should be an empty array not undefined. Now if any filters are set, then filters will be an array of objects like in your example.
I should emphasize that the URL example of undefined/[] was not my intention, you misunderstood the supposed output.

Yes you were right I overthought that.
